# What is a correct notion of an internal pseudofunctor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories, internal-categories, fibered-categories, grothendieck-construction

Let $C$ be a category internal to a category $K$. It is well known (for example see **Proposition 2.4** in the paper **Higher Dimensional Algebra VI: Lie 2-Algebra** by *Baez and Crans* https://digitalcommons.lmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1068&context=math_fac) that there is a strict 2-category $K$Cat consisting of categories in $K$ as objects, functors in $K$ as 1-morphisms and natural transformations in $K$ as 2-morphisms.

**My question is the following:**

Is there any existing notion of a pseudofunctor $F: C^{\rm{op}} \rightarrow K\rm{Cat}$? As of now, I could not find much about such notions.

**If I define such a notion naively as**

**.** every $x \in \rm{Ob}(C)$ is mapped to a category $F(x)$ in $K$,

**.** every $\gamma :x \rightarrow y \in \rm{Mor}(C)$ is mapped to a functor $\gamma^{*} : F(y) \rightarrow F(x)$ in $K$,

**.** such that functoriality hold upto certain choices of natural isomorphisms in $K$,

**.** such that "*these choices of natural isomorphisms*" satisfy the standard coherence properties similar to the usual category valued pseudofunctors,

**then what are the problems we may face?**

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: The current definition simply extracts an ordinary category from C, then writes down a pseudofunctor to KCat.  If one replaces x and γ with generalized elements (i.e., works in families controlled by presheaves), then the resulting definition has a good chance of being the “right” definition.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Sir,  the "current" definition means the definition I mentioned in the question here or the definition that is currently in use?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Sir, if possible can you elaborate your argument a bit?

Comment: The current definition (given in the question) talks about individual objects and individual morphisms of C.  Presumably, these are given by morphisms 1→Ob(C) and 1→Mor(C), where 1 is the terminal object of K.  This type of operation destroys most of the internal structure of C, e.g., if K was (say) topological spaces, then we would see C as an ordinary category, not as a topological category.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thank you Sir! I got the point. Can you please elaborate a bit on replacing $x$ and $y$ by  generalized elements? I mean I understand the for an usual category, we do the Yoneda embedding. But what do we usually do for internal categories in general?

Comment: Pseudofunctors whose domains are discrete $2$-category promotions of $1$-categories and whose codomains are the $2$-category of categories are usually referred to as [indexed categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+category); the keyword you're looking for is 'internal indexed category'. Such things exist, and as Dmitri says if you allow the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ to be arbitrary arrows $x:X\to{\bf Ob}_\mathcal{C}$ and the morphisms $f:x\to y$ of $\mathcal{C}$ to be arbitrary arrows $f:X\to{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{K}$ with $dom\circ f=x$ and $cod\circ f=y$(cont)

Comment: (cont) your definition probably shakes out just fine. (note that this 'working out' is essentially the faithful half of the Yoneda lemma)

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks! I am little confused, what is $X$ here?. Can you please suggest  any reference where these 'internal indexed categories" are mentioned?

Comment: $X$ is just an arbitrary object of $\mathcal{K}$, the ambient category (maybe I should have used $X'$ for the domain of $f$). You can read about internal category theory in some generality from pages 224-244 in [my notes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351884844_Category_Theory) on researchgate, with some additional stuff on externalization from p. 246-264. (I'm sure there are better references for internal indexed categories specifically, I just don't know of them off the top of my head; perhaps [here](https://digital.lib.washington.edu/researchworks/handle/1773/44365))

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks for your notes. I am going through it.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri No problem, I hope they're of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with pullbacks, with ${\sf C}$ an internal category in $\mathcal{C}$. We define a category $${\sf Ext( C})$$ called the *externalization* of ${\sf C}$ as follows:

1. The objects of ${\sf Ext(C)}$ are generalized elements of ${\sf Ob_C}$, that is arrows $x:X\to{\sf Ob_C}\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}$.
2. The arrows $f:x\to y$ of ${\sf Ext(C})$ are ordered pairs $(u,f)$, where $u:dom(x)\to dom(y)\in{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}$ and $f:dom(x)\to{\sf Hom_C}$ is a generalized element of ${\sf Hom_C}$, which commute appropriately with ${\sf dom}$, ${\sf cod}$, $x$ and $y$. That is, we have $${\sf dom}\circ f=x,$$ $${\sf cod}\circ f=y\circ u.$$
3. Identities on objects are given by the identity on their domains in the first coordinate and the postcomposition of that object with the internal identity selecting arrow for ${\sf C}$ in the second coordinate. That is, $$1_x=(1_{dom(x)},1_{\sf C}\circ x).$$
4. Composition is given pointwise in the first coordinate and by induced pullback arrows postcomposed with internal composition in the second coordinate. That is, for arrows $(u,f):y\to z$ and $(v,g):x\to y$ we define $$(u,f)\circ(v,g)=\big(u\circ v,\circ_{\sf C}\circ\langle f\circ v,g\rangle\big)$$ where $\langle f\circ v,g\rangle:dom(g)\to{\sf Hom_C\times_{_{Ob_C}}Hom_C}$ is a uniquely induced pullback arrow.

We can then consider a regular indexed category $$\Phi:{\sf Ext(C)}^{op}\to\mathcal{\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})$$ where ${\sf Cat}
(\mathcal{C})$ is the $2$-category of internal categories in $\mathcal{C}$, and this is naively the shortest answer to 'what is the correct notion of an internal indexed category'.

Note that we can externalize internal functors and natural transformations in similar fashion, yielding a $2$-functor $${\sf Ext}:{\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})\to\mathfrak{Cat}$$ which is faithful, but not generally full -- the above suggestion thusly isn't the right answer to 'what is the correct notion of an internal indexed category', in general.

We can obtain a full embedding by fixing the object we're externalizing from instead of using arbitrary objects from the base category, but we then lose faithfulness unless the object we choose is a [separator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator). Externalizing from a separator $S$ yields a full and faithful embedding $${\sf Ext}_S:{\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})\hookrightarrow\mathfrak{Cat}$$ allowing us to really work with internal data as though it were regular external data, so the answer to 'what is the correct notion of an internal indexed category' in a category admitting a separator $S$ would be a regular indexed category $$\Phi:{\sf Ext}_S({\sf C})^{op}\to{\sf Cat(}\mathcal{C}).$$

All of this is really an internal version of the family fibration for a category and is clearer through the lens of fibered category theory; for more details, see p. 246-264 of [these notes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351884844_Category_Theory).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have one question: So, I expect that after appropriate Grothendieck construction of the "internal pseudofunctor" in the sense of "internal indexed category", we will obtain a fibered category over $\rm{Ext}(C)$, which will be the externalisation of some category $D$ in $\mathcal{C}$, **but " the constructed fibered category will  not be just a category internal to $\mathcal{C}"$**. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Is there a way to get a fibration $F : D \rightarrow C$ over $C$ from the internal pseudofunctor, where $D$ is a category internal to $\mathcal{C}$ and $F$ is functor internal to $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri I'm not sure I understand your first comment, but regarding the second one we can probably go through Yoneda backwards to obtain such a 'fully internal' fibration from an internal indexed category as defined above -- I'll think about it today and edit if it works out.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Note that fibrations are most naturally internalized in an arbitrary $2$-category/bicategory (e.g. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fibration+in+a+2-category)) -- in order for this to work out in a $1$-category, I suspect we will need more than $\mathcal{C}$ having pullbacks.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri For example, if we go extreme and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a topos we can just work in the internal language of the topos and internalize all the definitions verbatim under their new interpretations; in this case, I can't see how anything could go wrong.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri I have answered the question you asked, so I don't see why you accepted the answer and then un-accepted it. If you would like to ask a separate question about how to 'fully internalize' the Grothendieck construction in a $1$-category that's fine, but it's a different question and should be asked separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations in the comments and also for the references. I accepted the answer now. That time I unaccepted, because in some portions of the answer, my understandings were incomplete that time, so I thought of understanding it completely and then accept it again. I apologise, if my un-accepting after accepting the answer sent some wrong intentions.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri No worries, I was just confused -- I have edited the answer to include more details.

Comment: Thanks for the additional edit.